# Enviar XML via POST

Tags: c#, xml, soap

Tenho o seguinte exemplo para enviar XML via POST:

```
public string EnviarXmlSoap(string methodName, string body)
    {
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://loja-s.tray.com.br/webservice/v2/ws_servidor.php?wsdl");
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)webRequest;
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/" + methodName);
        httpRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        httpRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        //Create Stream and Complete Request             
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.ASCII);

        StringBuilder soapRequest = new StringBuilder("<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"");
        soapRequest.Append(" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" ");
        soapRequest.Append("xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body>");
        soapRequest.Append(body);
        soapRequest.Append("</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");

        streamWriter.Write(soapRequest.ToString());
        streamWriter.Close();
        //Get the Response    
        HttpWebResponse wr = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader srd = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream());
        string resulXmlFromWebService = srd.ReadToEnd();
        return resulXmlFromWebService;
    }
```

Editei o código e agora está me retornando o seguinte erro:

`O servidor remoto retornou um erro: (404) Não Localizado.`

Comment: Por que você não adiciona um service reference deste webservice ?

Comment: Porque quando adiciono, por alguma razão, não aparece para mim acessar os métodos..

Comment: Você já tentou validar esse wsdl ? Eu tentei aqui e ele não validou. O erro foi o seguinte: The datatype 'http://loja-s.tray.com.br/webservice/v2/ws_servidor.php:Valor' is missing. Mas eu fiz um teste e inclui esse "Valor" no wsdl e a classe foi gerada normalmente

Comment: Validar? não... onde vc validou? preciso do xml que ele monta.. como faço para obter isso ??

Comment: https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/ , tambem usei o wsdl.exe e o erro foi o mesmo

Comment: preciso do xml que ele monta.. como faço para obter isso ??

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44836/discussion-between-robss70-and-novato).

Comment: Deu certo do jeito que está agora... exceto a url... entrei em contato com o suporte e me passaram outra Url e deu certo.